# Tor NEWNYM is NOT working with C#

Tags: c#, .net, tor

I have reviewed every question/response on stackoverflow regarding how to change the exit node IP for Tor programmatically to no avail. Every answer says that all you have to do is connect to the Tor control port and issue the "signal newnym" command, and you'll get a new exit IP. I'm using the [Minimalistic Telnet Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library) to issue the following:

```
TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection("127.0.0.1", 9051);
tc.WriteLine("AUTHENTICATE \"pwd\"");
tc.WriteLine("SIGNAL NEWNYM");
tc.WriteLine("QUIT");
```

I've added line endings, tried different Telnet libraries and direct TCP connections, and none of it works. I'm scraping a page on our development server that displays the requesting IP, and when I call this page in a loop, stopping on occasion to issue the "newnym" command, the IP address never changes. Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Sorry to submit what appears to be a duplicate, but since none of the answers work, I don't really consider it a dupe. Thanks.

Comment: What does it say in your Controller program's log? What responses do those commands return on your system? I used those commands in Telnet on my Debian system and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I get "250 OK" from the system, so that's not it. I'll have to review the logs and see, but I'm not getting any kinds of errors.

Comment: Checked the logs, and I see 'Rate limiting NEWNYM request: delaying by x second(s)'. However, even when I only call NEWNYM every 10 seconds (the Tor documented limit is 5 seconds), nothing happens.

Comment: How are you checking if Vidalia (or whatever you are using) has gotten you a new IP?

Comment: @Maxwell -- I put an .aspx page on one of our dev servers, and it sticks the "REMOTE_ADDR" server variable in a div that I scrape.

Comment: Did you find any solution?? I'm having a similar problem, but from php. I'm sure the connection is established and I'm getting "250 OK" after the signal newnym.

Comment: J-Rou -- Nope, never did work for me. I ended up spinning up multiple simultaneous instances of Tor/Polipo to increase the number of exit nodes available. Don't know if that's a possibility for you, but it helped my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a TOR relay the signal NEWNYM has no effect. it works only for TOR clients for browsing the internet. It means new identity, new circuit.

If Tor chose to ignore a signal (such as NEWNYM), this event will not be
  sent.  Note that some options (like ReloadTorrcOnSIGHUP) may affect the
  semantics of the signals here.

Note that the HALT (SIGTERM) and SHUTDOWN (SIGINT) signals do not currently
  generate any event.

Answer (score 1):

`NEWNYM` does not destroy existing circuits, it marks them dirty and builds new ones (among other things). Just dispose the existing TCP connections and when you build new ones you will get a new IP.